# anyone using Wacom Tablet with Pro Tools

Tags: pro-tools

I'm having terrible problems.

When I "Pan/Scroll" on the timeline, there's a huge lag and generally unpredictable behavior. The timeline will continue to scroll for up to a few seconds after I let go.

This wasn't an issue for me until Pro Tools 11 + 12.

Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: In use a wacom tablet but i'm not experiencing that. I assume you installed the latest Wacom drivers?

Comment: Yes, you really have to keep your Wacom drivers up to date or you do get unexpected behaviors like this.

Answer (score -1):

sometimes the nib in the pen will get a catch on it, and it refuses to "unclick" when you let up. i've had this happen mostly on my older wacoms.

what i usually do is take the nib out with some tweezers and gently file down the edges of the inside tip, then re-insert it. i'm not 100% sure that's your problem, but i've had to do it a handful of times over the years of using wacom tabs.

if it is not a physical problem with the pen nib, are you using windows? i find that disabling all of the little windows pen input extras makes using a tablet a lot smoother.

hope that helps

Comment: no the user reports a different problem, it's not a malfunctioning nib, it's pro tools/wacom problem...